# Help to find an equivalent for encoder H9730 - 1926 (HEDS-9730)

Tags: identification, encoder

I need help to identify the encoder from the photo. Seems H9730 is actually HEDS-9730 but I have no idea what the second number is (1926). I guess the resolution? I saw that even on heads there are different variants of resolutions. I need to get that info in order to be able to find an equivalent.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a HEDS-9730#Q50. Currently 500+ instock at Digikey.
https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/broadcom-limited/HEDS-9730-Q50/825026

The "1926" shows the manufacture date code in YYWW format: 20**19** week **26**, so somewhere around the end of June.

[image]

Image taken from datasheet under the documentation tab

https://www.broadcom.com/products/motion-control-encoders/incremental-encoders/transmissive-encoders/heds-9730q50#documentation

Answer (score 0):

Seems the resolution is actually that "Q" which is 180 LPI

Comment: Thanks for the interesting question. Can you please expand this answer slightly to explain how you know that "Q" is the resolution, and how you know. Link to a relevant site would be useful. Doing what you can of this makes the Q&A useful to others who have similar problems in future || ((And, I'd love to know as well :-) )). .

Comment: Datasheet page 11 [here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/678/V02-1747EN-952646.pdf) provides that information. Could you add that to your answer. An image of  page 11 would be informative if you can be bothered adding it (with attribution). Not essential - your choice.